# Print client side from web application using Zebra printer

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, barcode, zebra-printers

Is there a way (and what is that way) to print to a locally connected (client side) Zebra printer (using custom ZPLs and Layouts) from a web application (IIS, C#)?

I need to be able to print more or less generic data, so I can't really use the normal printer screens, because the layouts/ZPL we use are customly made and generated automatically.

What do I need to create in order to have a connection between the web page and the client? Maybe ActiveX or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at jZebra, a small embedable Java applet which facilitates printing to label printers. 
The applet is fully controllable from JavaScript, and there are a lot of samples and tutorials. I am using it on Zebra GK420t, but any label printer can be used, since the applet uses raw mode printing.

It's open source, see it here: http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/